# spring Aspectj within pointcut expression

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I tried to add some benchmarking aspect to my java app and configure it using xml,
but for some reason the I can't get the within designator to work.

the aspect should work for all methods in the components package and sub packages instead of the aspect package (in order to avoid endless loops).

```
    <aop:aspect id="aspectBenchmark" ref="benchmarkAspect" >

        <aop:around method="logAround" pointcut="within(com.app.components.**) &amp;&amp; !within(com.app.components.aspect.**)"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

BTW,
when i changed the pointcut expression to "execution(@javax.ws.rs.POST * *(..))" (just because I wanted make sure I have nothing wrong with the aspect class), it worked...
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try with `within(com.app.components..*` instead of `within(com.app.components.**`

Comment: or `execution(com.app.components.**)`

Comment: i tried both without success...

Comment: @suninsky suggestion works for me